# How to insert multiple variables into a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, var

Im really new to JavaScript and I was wondering how would I be able to insert multiple varibles into a string?

```
var adjective1 = 'amazing';
var adjective2 = 'fun';
var adjective3 = 'entertaining';



var madLib = "The Intro to JavaScript course is (adjective1). James and Julia are so (adjective2). I cannot wait to work through the rest of this (adjective3) content!";
console.log(madLib);
```

Comment: Same sort of thing as in the answer there, except use `(` and `)` delimiters instead of `${` and `}` delimiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

```js
var adjective1 = 'amazing';
var adjective2 = 'fun';
var adjective3 = 'entertaining';

var madLib = `The Intro to JavaScript course is ${adjective1}. James and Julia are so ${adjective2}. I cannot wait to work through the rest of this ${adjective3} content!`;
console.log(madLib);
```

Comment: it works thank you, and sorry for being a noob in JS  ill accept the answer soon since SO says I have to wait a few minutes

Comment: @Evelyn, you are most welcome, happy to help:)